# Apache cordova ios application floating cursor issue

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins, html-framework-7, apache-cordova, cordova-ios

**Apache cordova ios application floating cursor issue**
Please find the screen shot from app as follows:

1.Cursor is misaligned with input text box.
[cursor wrong position](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hInFq.jpg)

2.Cursor is getting overlapped with page header. 
[Overlapped with header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zFCuj.jpg)

Comment: Which version of xCode / iOS ?

Comment: IOS : 12.1, X Code: 10.1

Comment: Had the same issue some weeks ago, just installed this plugin : https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/keyboard/ and it solved the issue. It's because the keyboard pushes the view too high. There are many workarounds for this issue. Let me know if installing the plugin is enough for you.

Comment: cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard this plugin is already installed. Even if we scroll the page (while keyboard is in opened state) cursor overlapping with header. ( https://i.stack.imgur.com/zFCuj.jpg )

Comment: Could you try this workaround : 
            `window.addEventListener('keyboardWillHide', () => {
                window.scrollTo(0,0);
                document.body.scrollTop = 0;
            });`(put this code in `app.component.ts` inslide the platform ready promise)

Comment: Using cordova and framework 7 for UI. Added above code within onDeviceReady function. Still not resolved.

Comment: use margin top input box. that should resolve this